# `expect_any_instance_of` equivalent for PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, rspec, phpunit

I am a rails programmer exploring PHP and PHPUnit. I've been struggling a bit with switching over from RSpec to PHPUnit.

More specifically RSpec has a really nice stub method called [`expect_any_instance_of`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-6/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) that allows you to stub any instance of any class.

I am struggling to find the equivalent in PHPUnit.

Here is my scenario in code:

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SomeClass
{
    public function testMethod()
    {
        $api_interface = new RemoteAPIClassObject();
        $result = $api_interface->makeCall()
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $result->api_response);
    }
}
?>
```

I would like to stub the method `makeCall` that is part of the `RemoteAPIClassObject` instance. Is there any way to do that in PHPUnit so I don't actually have to make a remote API call to remote server every time I run my test suite?

I have read about PHPUnit [test doubles and class mocks](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) however it seems like all the PHPUnit stub/mock methods return an stub instance which is not what I want since the method I am trying to stub is further down the call stack.

In rspec I would just use the method I mentioned earlier to stub the call:

`expect_any_instance_of(RemoteAPIClassObject).to receive(:makeCall).and_return(some_stubbed_object)`

Perhaps my strategy is off and I need to rethink my test?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the PHP world. I've used `Mockery` in the past (PHPUnit mock is not as expressive). For mocking http calls, `php-vcr` is a nice project.

Answer (score 1):

You would create a mock object of your class and use that.

```
$api_interface = $this->getMockBuilder('RemoteAPIClassObject')
    ->setMethods(['makeCall'])
    ->getMock();

$api_interface->expects($this->once())
    ->method('makeCall')
    ->willReturn((object)['api_response' => 'foo']);
```

Doing this however is not a good practice.  We are mocking the class that we are looking to test.  It would be better to allow for the the class that you are testing to receive a mock connection that we can pass in to the `RemoteAPIClassObject` and have it stubbed for a response.  This would allow your code to not have to actually make the remote api call and allows for flexibility in the connections that you can make.

I am not able to provide more detail without seeing more about the object that you are testing.

Comment: +1 for 'It would be better to allow for the the class that you are testing to receive a mock connection'